# IPv6 loopback address http://0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - browser can't connect. Method getRemoteHost()

Tags: http, firefox, java-8, ipv6

Method `String domain = request.getRemoteHost();` returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` IPv6 address. LAN card is configured to support IPv6 protocol, Firefox as well: `network.dns.disableIPv6 false`, and Java 1.8.0_141-b15 64-bit is installed. But if I enter `http://0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` it shows an error or shows the results on Google (??). If I enter `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it shows my project's webpage. How can it be fixed? My goal is not to disable IPv6, but to support both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols.

Proposed solution was to add brackets: `http://[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]`. And it's working. But now we have to add brackets manually, and only if protocol is IPv6. Perhaps `getRemoteHost()` should be updated to better support IPv6?

I found information about literal IPv6 addresses in network resource identifiers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address):

> Colon (:) characters in IPv6 addresses may conflict with the
>   established syntax of resource identifiers, such as URIs and URLs. The
>   colon has traditionally been used to terminate the host path before a
>   port number.[8] To alleviate this conflict, literal IPv6 addresses are
>   enclosed in square brackets in such resource identifiers, for example:
>
> ```
> http://[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]/
> ```
>
> When the URL also contains a port number the notation is:
>
> ```
> https://[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:443/
> ```

So it seems Java problem...? Now working on IPv6 regex..

Comment: Try `http://[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]`

Comment: Yes, it's working :). But why the  request.getRemoteHost(); returns address without brackets? So it's Java fault?

Comment: Not a fault of Java. The browser expects the bracket syntax to parse the request as an IPv6 address.

Comment: Ok, I'm using response.sendRedirect(newUrl); So I must insert the brackets manually? Looking like not a serious workaround.. The Java should be updated - or perhaps there is another solution? And another problem - now I have to determine if it is IPv4 or IPv6 protocol - another task for CPU..

Comment: Sorry, don't know of a better solution as I haven't faced this problem before. You could do a check to see if the host name is an IPv6 host and, if so, do the manual adding of the brackets. Don't have a better solution for you about that, perhaps someone else knows better.

Comment: There is actually an RFC that covers this: _[Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)_. If you are using the address literal in a URL, you must insert the brackets, but in other circumstances, you do not want the brackets. The URL requires this because IPv6 addresses use colons, which are interpreted by things like browsers as the separator for the port number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask Java for a host name, you'll get a host name, not a URI fragment. There is nothing wrong with that. If you actually want a URI, you should ask for a URI:

```
String host = "::1", path = "/";
URI uri = new URI("http", host, path, null);
System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
```

will print

```
URI: http://[::1]/
```

But if you construct the URI string manually instead, it will be *your* responsibility to add brackets when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy solution:

```
public static boolean isIPv6(String IP) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
    return address instanceof Inet6Address;
}
```

But it would be very nice to have a method `getRemoteHost(true | false)` to get IPv6 address with brackets or not.